# snap message: Password storage in Chromium

Tags: password, snap, chromium

Upon starting Chromium today, the file `/snap/chromium/2319/firstrun/password-en.html` is loaded, displaying a message titled "Password storage in Chromium". The message indicates that a password problem has been fixed, and that I should rename `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Login Data` to `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Login Data.old`. I have not had a password problem, but regardless: can anyone confirm that this is a valid request? Is there further information on this online?

Answer (score 4):

If the file displayed is inside `/snap/chromium/` then it comes from the official package, built by the Ubuntu developers, so on that alone, it's genuine. We know this because the `/snap/chromium/` is the snap package mounted from an unmodified read-only file delivered from the snap store.

Looking at the file in question, it does indeed look like this:

---

## Password storage in Chromium

Password storage via the Gnome keyring has been fixed, but for it to work, you have to rename your old `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Login Data` file so that a new, working one can replace it.

We suggest you to rename it to Login Data.old. You can do so through your file manager or by opening a terminal and entering

```bash
cd ~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/
mv "Login Data" "Login Data.old"
```

This way, in case something goes wrong (and please file a bug report in Launchpad if so), you can always reverse the action by renaming the file back to Login Data.

Disable this message by creating the file `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Login Data.old`.

---

The logic around when this is displayed was [introduced](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Echromium-team/chromium-browser/+git/snap-from-source/commit/?id=783497f8517231dd0b473300a6b1e66762b6bbbf)* recently.

*If that link doesn't work ([issue caused by the tilde](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370143/prevent-markdown-links-from-escaping-the-tilde-character-on-stack-exchange?r=SearchResults)), copy and paste in the URL bar the address below:

https://git.launchpad.net/~chromium-team/chromium-browser/+git/snap-from-source/commit/?id=783497f8517231dd0b473300a6b1e66762b6bbbf